# The method assertEquals(double, double) from the type Assert is deprecated and I need to make it like that

Tags: java

Okay, so I'm doing an homework and I have to create an object called Bonus.

And I have to do a test. In that case, I'm doing testing [getBonusPercent]

But yet, it tell it doesn't work because The method assertEquals(double, double) from the type Assert is deprecated.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. This should worked fine

Also, sorry for my broken English.

I tried other Assert but so far, nothing work.
Also, i have import static [org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;] wrote in the script

In the main methode

```
private float bonusPercentage;

Bonus(float bonus) {
  this.bonusPercentage = bonus;
}

public float getBonusPercent() {
  return this.bonusPercentage;
}
```

The test

```
this.bonus = new Bonus(BONUS);

assertEquals(BONUS, this.bonus.getBonusPercent());
```

assertEquals(double, double) from the type Assert is deprecated.

Comment: javascript is not java

Comment: Use the variant that accepts a delta. Else the comparison might fail just due to limited double-precision. You can use a small delta like `0.00001` of course.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) to understand why this is necessary and why that method is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `assertEquals(BONUS, this.bonus.getBonusPercent(), 0.01d);` 
This will make sure, that the comparation does not fail in some cases where double is not precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `assertEquals(double, double)` is deprecated because a newer version of it, `assertEquals(double, double, double)` should be used.

The thrid parameter here is a delta value. It indicates an acceptable difference between the 2 given double values.

Simply set the third parameter to 0 to check if the numbers are equal, or use a small delta value.

Comment: Do not use `0`. It happens so quick that something like `0.2 == 0.1 + 0.1` fails just because of double precision letting it end up at `0.199999999`. Use a small delta like `0.00001`.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) to understand why this is necessary and why that method is deprecated.

Comment: Using `0`  completely defeats the purpose of using the not-deprecated method. It is exactly the same as if using the deprecated variant. This is even more dangerous as you do not get a warning anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When you find a deprecated method, you have to look in the docs for the proposed alternative. In this case, you will find that you have to use `Assert.equals(double, double, double)` where the last double is the delta, or the maximum amount of difference allowed to still be considered equal, as per the [specification in the docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double,%20double))

[Deprecated method with proposed alternative](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double))